# How to Hardcode password in cvsCheckout command?

Tags: shell, cvs

I am remote user to cvs repository and my CVSROOT is

```
:ext:aa81000@cvs.qintra.com:/opt/scm/cvs/home/repository
```

and when run the cvsCheckout command it is prompting for password in runtime.My requirement is to wrote a shell script to do checkout on everyday so when i use cvsCheckOut command in shellscript it will prompt for password.Can any one tell how to input password for cvsCheckout at compile time i mean in the shell script.
Please can ay one help

Comment: Have you tried `cvs login`?

Comment: ya many cvs options ask for password